# Rich faces jquery

Tags: jquery, richfaces

I have lloked at the Rich Faces jquery integration at the live demo exadel site.

Is there any more documentation or tutorial available on the same ?

I would like to know what is possible and what is not possible with this integration

Edit:

Well I am changing my question completely here. Well I have a jsf component (exadel fiji chart to be precise). I would like it to rerender after I click a a4j:button. The action of this button is to retreive some data from the database.

It seems exadel fiji charts do not rerender on the a4j submit. And on reading up their forum it seems we have to use jquery update to rerender the chart alone.

Can anyone guide me on how to go about doing the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Richfaces` includes indeed a version of the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) framework. This will allow you to use `jQuery` on your pages, as well as some `jQuery` plugins.

However, you are looking for something different, which is the customization of the `<rich:tab>` components. You can do that, see [here](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_tabPanel.html) and [here](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_tab.html).

Another solution is to use some jQuery tab plugin, but this will generate HTML code, and you will not have a corresponding JSF component.